# Return table CHECK Constraints in JOOQ

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have a table in my PostgreSQL database, which was generated using the following Jooq query:

```
context.createTable("object_brick_car")
        .column(field(name("id"), Integer.class), SQLDataType.INTEGER.identity(true))
        .primaryKey("id")
        .column("record_id", INTEGER)
        .column("field_name", VARCHAR(255))
        .column("capacity", INTEGER)
        .column("power", INTEGER.default_(0))
        .constraints(
            constraint("company_index_check")
                .check(field(name("power"), INTEGER).between(0, 500)),
            constraint("object_brick_car_foreign_key").foreignKey("record_id").references("object_store_car", "id")
        ).execute();
```

This table generated correctly, logger shows the following SQL query being executed:

```
create table "object_brick_car" ("id" int generated by default as identity not null, "record_id" int, "field_name" varchar(255), "capacity" int, "power" int default 0, primary key ("id"), constraint "company_index_check" check ("power" between 0 and 500), constraint "object_brick_car_foreign_key" foreign key ("record_id") references "object_store_car" ("id"))
```

I want to retrieve metainformation about this table using Jooq API. I can collect information about data types, foreign and primary keys, uniqness constraints, etc.

But when I tried to collect information about **"company_index_check"** via Table.getChecks() I received empty list:

```
Table metadata
                   Indices: 
                  Primary key: constraint "object_brick_car_pkey" primary key ("id") Checks: {} 
                   Foreign keys: constraint "object_brick_car_foreign_key"
```

Is there any option to receive a list of checks via Jooq API and map them onto Check objects?
The Jooq version is 3.18.7

Answer (score 1):

As of jOOQ 3.19, `CHECK` constraints aren't available from `org.jooq.Meta` API, but there's no reason not to support those in the future:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/16190

Note the historic reason for some meta data being absent in `org.jooq.Meta` is simply because that API is mainly JDBC `DatabaseMetaData` backed, and that API is very limited. But jOOQ has internal vendor specific queries used for the code generator that can also be used in `org.jooq.Meta`